# Chotto and sukoshi ....kudasai?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

Is it okay if I say 'sukoshi matte kudasai' instead of 'chotto matte kudasai' ?

Comment: *Formal* 'shou-shou omati kudasai' > 'sukoshi matte kudasai' > 'chotto matte (kudasai)' *Informal*

Answer (score 3):

yes, if you translate it to English they have very similar meanings.
Assuming that you knew in Japanese there are formal and informal terms, chotto is informal and generally only used in speech.

Comment: I agree that "chotto" is rather informal. However, I don't think "chotto" has any nuance regarding superiority: Some might be offended when the speaker uses "chotto", interpreting the use of informal terms as the lack of respect for him/her, but that can sorely be explained by the informality. Compare with "ご苦労さま", which actually has such nuance.

Comment: Who used 'chotto' here? He/she or you?